# Position Div onClick, and hide when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with class `.toggleBox` that is visibly hidden.  When clicking on an `input` my JavaScript can show the `.toggleBox` div, but I am not sure how to hide the div again if clicking anywhere outside of the `.toggleBox` div.

I would like to toggle the box so that it is hidden or shown depending on it's current state and whether the click occured inside `.toggleBox` or outside of it.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SJVz5/

Here is the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="myInput">Click in input</label>
    <input type="text" class="js-input" id="myInput" />
    <div class="toggleBox">
        Some information
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.js-input').click(function() {
    $('.toggleBox').css({
        top : 22 + 'px',
        left : 91 + 'px'
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.toggleBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    left: 99999px;
    padding: 15px;;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SJVz5/2/?

Comment: Almost, if clicking in the `.toggleBox` div it should not be hidden again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have updated your script , please check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/SJVz5/3/, i hope it's that you want

you have to add `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: That works great!  I didn't know about event.stopPropagation().  Can I ask, why does the `toggleBox` have a .click() method that contains `$(this).show()`?  Since it's already shown can that be removed or am I missing something?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Seems I'm a bit late but I have an easier answer with shorter codes
http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/SJVz5/4/

```
$('html').click(function () {
    $('.toggleBox').toggle().css({
        top: 22 + 'px',
        left: 91 + 'px'
    });
});

$('.toggleBox').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was just commenting and was not familiar with `event.stopPropagation()`.  I had googled for a while and saw an old jQuery method called `.toggle()` that might have helped me but that was deprecated. Thanks!

Comment: @Mdd you are mistaking the two toggle(). One is deprecated like you said which is a method(JQuery API), the other is an animation effect to display/hide element which is exactly what suits your needs best. See here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ It is still active which you can tell from the demo as you are using the latest JQuery library and obviously the demo works!