# jQuery nested animation conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I created a simple multi level push menu with the following code:

HTML

```
<li class="mobile_main_menu_headers">
  <h3 class='expand'>Top</h3>
  <ul class="mobile_main_menu_sub">
     <li class="mobile_main_menu_sub_back">Back</li>
     <li><a href="">Sub</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Sub</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Sub</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
$(".mobile_main_menu_headers").click(function(){               
    $(this).find('.mobile_main_menu_sub').animate({left:'0px'});
});

$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
});
```

The problem is when clicking `.mobile_main_menu_sub_back`, the animation does go to `left: 100%` but then immediately jumps back to `left: 0px` afterwards. I've created a simple jsfiddle you can view here:

http://jsfiddle.net/M8N6f/

Click the **Top**  text to see the animation slide left. Then click the **Back** text to see the issue.

I just want to the **back** button to animate the ul to the right, that's it.

Thanks

Comment: When you click on Back it is part of .mobile_main_menu_headers so it will trigger your first function that's why it goes back in again. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
$(".expand").click(function(){             
    $('.mobile_main_menu_sub').animate({left:'0px'});
});

$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/M8N6f/2/)
I've updated your code and made it simple, why are you writing it like that? For a specific reason or other functions you didn't include here?

EDIT: In case you have multiple menu elements
[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/M8N6f/5/)

```
$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
    event.stopPropagation(); //Add this line;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, works perfectly :)  What do you mean "writing it like that?" The class names or the algorithm? Haha if it's the algorithm I guess I'm just so tired I can't reason properly anymore  :p

Comment: I'll accept your answer in a few minutes, once SO lets me  :)

Comment: @user2028856 "writing like that" I meant your first function $(".mobile_main_menu_headers").click(function(){         
    $(this).find('.mobile_main_menu_sub').animate({left:'0px'});
}); why did you use so complicated selector where you can use a simple one? More efficient, and most importantly, will work :)

Comment: Okay actually I just forgot to mention that I have several more menu items. So I had to use $(this).find() to find the appropriate sub menu to display

Comment: Have a look at my jsfiddle again please, I've just realized that you original method displays all of the sub menu elements at once. That's why I used the $(this).find() method

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I have updated my answer, you just need to add a simple line that's all.

Comment: @Godinall - Great catch, looks familiar.

Comment: @Chase ah didn't come to the bottom of yours really. If you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588388/position-div-onclick-and-hide-when-clicked-outside/23588519#23588519 I have already used this method previously. Also I didn't use the "e" attribute in the second function which makes it more readable :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply stop the **event propagation** from **bubbling upward** by returning false from the event handler on the back `li`:

```
$(".mobile_main_menu_headers").click(function(){               
    $(this).find('.mobile_main_menu_sub').animate({left:'0px'});
});

$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
    return false;
});
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/M8N6f/3/)

Alternatively, jQuery has a function that does just that [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

> Prevents the event from **bubbling** up the DOM tree, **preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.**

```
$(".mobile_main_menu_headers").click(function(){               
    $(this).find('.mobile_main_menu_sub').animate({left:'0px'});
});

$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/M8N6f/4/)

You can read more about Events, Event Propagation, Bubbling and more [here](https://github.com/ChaseWest/Blog/blob/master/May-2014/Events.md).

Answer (score 0):

The problem your code is not working is:

You have binded click event to .mobile_main_menu_headers which is containing the `<li>`. So when the you click the back link in the `<li>` even the parent `.mobile_main_menu_headers` click is also trigger. i.e the event is bubbling up

You can solve this by the following methods:

remove the click event from the container .mobile_main_menu_headers and bind it to .expand element.

```
$(".expand").click(function(){             
            $('.mobile_main_menu_sub').animate({left:'0px'});
        });
```

stopEventPropogation, in the '.mobile_main_menu_sub_back' click event.

```
$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
});
```

or

```
$('.mobile_main_menu_sub_back').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent('ul').animate({left:'100%'});
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```